# Rails jQuery not working in asset pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

When I place this jQuery code in the view file, it works fine:

```
$('.messages-link').click(function (event) {
  $.getScript(this.href);
  history.pushState(null, "", this.href);
});
```

But when I put it in useful.js, and require useful.js in application.js, it doesn't work, it isn't called.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require underscore
//= require useful
```

I know that useful.js is successfully being included in the asset pipeline because there is another function in there that is definitely being called from the same view file.

Why does the jQuery function not work?

Comment: Maybe the element is not on the page yet... try to wrap it on a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you forgotten to place your code inside a DOM ready function? Perhaps your DOM has not loaded before you try to attach the listener?

```
$(function() {

  $('.messages-link').click(function (event) {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    history.pushState(null, "", this.href);
  });

});
```

Comment: I had indeed forgotten. Thank you. I need to learn about DOMs.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that if you put it in your view the element `.messages-link` exists in the DOM.

If you put it in useful then the file gets bundled in `application.js` and it is loaded in the `<HEAD></HEAD>` on your html before the view that has `.messages-link` is loaded.

A possible solution is to change the binding like this:

```
$('.messages-link').on('click', function (event) {
  $.getScript(this.href);
  history.pushState(null, "", this.href);
});
```

Which works with dynamically added elements.

Comment: I tried this (without @riarcombe's DOM ready function) and I'm afraid it still didn't work. Is the DOM ready function also necessary?

Comment: Ah, my bad. should have been `$(document).on('click', '.messages-link', function() {})`. Glad you got it to work anyways.